# Angular 11 - Increment index value in html

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, increment

I have a variable in my ts that contains a value of 3 (array length), I want to use it in my html to increment the value of index ([0]) until the value of 3 is reached.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceQuizOverview" matSort>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="question_text">
            <th class="font" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Questions</th>
            <td class="font" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.quiz_records[0].question_text}}</td>
          </ng-container>
  
          <ng-container matColumnDef="user_answers">
            <th class="font" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Answer</th>
            <td class="font" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.quiz_records[0].user_answers}}</td>
          </ng-container>
</table>
```

ts

```
 quiz_recordsLength.length: number = 3;
```

Comment: check `*ngFor` directive

Answer (score 1):

You should check, [NgForOf Directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables). This should solve your issue.

Also, for future questions, please remember this: [How much research effort is expected of stack overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Posting a new question should be your last resort.